# Is the use of window.location.href("javascript://code"); just as bad as eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

For instance:

```
    eval("alert('Hello there!');");

    // is just as bad as?

    window.location.href = "javascript:alert('Hello there!');void(0);";
```

Comment: Who are we to judge what's good and what's bad? Yes, it's just as bad.

Comment: I think it's even worse because you add much more overhead.

Comment: You killed the sweet ethics of javascript !! No offence ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's the same : the string after `"javascript:"` is evaluated to be executed.

At least the first bad solution is more direct and obvious...

For a more general insight about why eval is evil, I'd redirect you to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

But why would you use this kind of things ? It's very very hard to find a legitimate case where it would simplify your code.